# Does http2MaxRequests in istio DestinationRules per-pod or per-service?

Tags: istio, envoyproxy, servicemesh

The definition is below(https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/destination-rule/), I wonder if the limit is per-pod or per-service?

```
Maximum number of active requests to a destination. Default 2^32-1. Please note that this is applicable to both HTTP/1.1 and HTTP2.
```